# Extract a zip file directly from the jarfile

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to extract the content of a zip file contained into my jarfile (in fact it contains a few files that can be edited and need to be extracted at the first use, even if there is no internet connection). I can extract a single file from my jar if I know its name using MyMainClass.getResource("myfile.zip") but I would like to extract its content without having to extract myfile.zip and delete it after. Is it possible with java 8?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Yes and I did a few things working using temporary files but this is not what I want and I'm not able to get it working without them :/

Comment: Could you show some examples of programs working with temporary files?